# Is there a way to manually reset the onchange event using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, onchange

Is this possible? I tried setting `selectedIndex` but that didn't work.

What I have is a problem with an onChange event on a touchscreen device. The onChange event with a selection from a dropdown works fine the first time, but doesn't seem to reset when I call the form again, even though I reset the form itself.

The problem is that the selections on the first dropdown,  after the first one, depend on the onChange event calling a function to generate the next select dropdown.  However, on the device itself, the onChange event doesn't seem to trigger, if the item is re-selected in the first box. Difficult to understand, but I thought if I could reset the onChange event for that select box element, then the onChange event would fire properly again.

Comment: you must be more specific ;) do you want to clear all listeners or do you want to reset the selectedIndex of something?

Comment: reset? you mean like rerun it or change it with another function?

Comment: You need to provide more details that this. You only wrote one line...

Comment: Sorry.  What I have is a problem with an onChange event on a touchscreen device.  The onChange with the select works fine the first time, but doesn't seem to reset when I call the form again, even though I reset the form itself.  The problem is that select statements after the first one depend on the onChange calling a function to generate the next select dropdown, but on the device the onChange doesn't seem to trigger if the item is re-selected in the first box.  Tough to understand, I know, but I thought if I could reset Javascript's "memory" for that select box that it would trigger onChang

Comment: @pimvdb I think the -1 for my question might have been a bit premature, as my follow-up comment should prove.  Thanks to the downgrade, I assume that nobody will look seriously at the question or comments anymore.

Comment: @FlashFan  I guess, in response to the first comment, clearing all listeners might work(?).

Comment: @robert smith: Not sure what you mean, I didn't downvote, just corrected your spelling.

Comment: @pimvdb  Sorry. My mistake.  But thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

You want to trigger the onchange handler? `document.getElementById('yourelement').onchange()`.